# C# - SELECT FROM query works in MS SQL but not when run within SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am running a query to find a the latest order from a list of orders and then trying to see if the ordered date was longer than 3 months.

I have written a query in MS SQL which seems to be running ok but when I put into my C# code, it throws me an error

Here is the code in MS SQL

```
SELECT CompanyID 
FROM ( SELECT CompanyID, 
              OrderedDateTime, 
              Rank() over (partition by CompanyID order by OrderID DESC) RankOrder 
       FROM dbo.Orders OD1) TBL 
WHERE RankOrder = 1
AND OrderedDateTime <= DATEADD(mm,-2,GetDate())
```

This is the code in my project

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyID FROM dbo.Companies WHERE CompanyID IN (SELECT CompanyID FROM (SELECT CompanyID, OrderedDateTime, Rank() over (partition by CompanyID order by OrderID DESC) RankOrder FROM dbo.Orders OD1) TBL WHERE RankOrder = 1 AND OrderedDateTime <= DATEADD(mm,-3,getDate())";
```

When I execute the MS SQL Query, it gives a list of Company IDs which is correct but when I run the code in C#, it gives the following error:

```
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'TBL'.
```

Can anyone please explain as to why this is happening and how to go about fixing it?

Thanks

Comment: The two queries are not the same ? `SELECT CompanyID FROM (SELECT ...`   versus `SELECT CompanyID FROM dbo.Companies WHERE CompanyID IN (SELECT... `   ?

Answer (score 1):

You have miss a `)` at the end

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyID FROM dbo.Companies WHERE CompanyID IN (SELECT CompanyID FROM (SELECT CompanyID, OrderedDateTime, Rank() over (partition by CompanyID order by OrderID DESC) RankOrder FROM dbo.Orders OD1) TBL WHERE RankOrder = 1 AND OrderedDateTime <= DATEADD(mm,-3,getDate()))";
```

Or should I say you have "extra" statement compare with your "SQL" in "MS SQL"?

```
SELECT CompanyID FROM dbo.Companies WHERE CompanyID IN
```